# Is there a way to create ACL's from scratch in powershell, as opposed to copying existing ones and modifying them?

Tags: windows, powershell, access-control-list

I know that I can copy existing ACLs using get-acl and then modify them using set-acl, but is there a way I can create a new, blank acl and then add in what I need? For example:

```
$foo = new-acl
#push some access rules into $foo
set-acl C:\myFolder $foo
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the .NET object:

```
$emptyACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
```

Note, I found this by using the Get-Member function to find the TypeName:

```
$ACL = Get-ACL C:\some_directory
$ACL | Get-Member
   TypeName: System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
  Name                            MemberType     Definition
  ----                            ----------     ----------
  .........................................................
```